# Suppose p(x) is irreducible in F[x] and E is an extension field of F. Suppose also p(x) has a root in E. Prove that deg p(x) | [E:F]

Tags: abstract-algebra

Suppose p(x) is irreducible in F[x] and E is an extension field of F. Suppose also p(x) has a root in E. Prove that deg p(x) | [E:F].

Where do I begin with this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\alpha$ is a root of $p(x)$ in $E$, then $F(\alpha)$ is a subfield of $E$ and 
$$[E:F]=[E:F(\alpha)][F(\alpha):F]=[E:F(\alpha)]\cdot\deg p(x).$$

Comment: Oh, ok! It makes tons more sense. I forgot that equation. Thanks!

Comment: Please don’t take it amiss when I say that in field theory, the multiplicativity of degree is something that must never be forgotten.